# List.clear() affect another untouched variable

Tags: java

I am making a java program to make multiple sequence alignment using genetic algorithm. At first, I got JavaHeap error because I created too many instances. So I tried to fix it by re-use the object using clear() method for List. However, when I use clear(), it affect another variable become null. Here is my code snippet:

```
private void crossover() throws Exception {
    Collections.shuffle(p);
    p1 = p.pop();
    p2 = p.pop();
    System.out.println("CROSSOVER antara " + p1 + " dan " + p2);
    p.add(p1);
    p.add(p2);

    Collections.shuffle(cutPoint);
    cp = cutPoint.pop();
    cutPoint.add(cp);

    k1 = pop.get(getPOP(p1)).getKromosom();
    k2 = pop.get(getPOP(p2)).getKromosom();
    System.out.println("k1 [" + k1.size() + "]" + k1.toString()); //PRINT1
    System.out.println("k2 [" + k2.size() + "]" + k2.toString()); //PRINT1

    c1.clear();
    c2.clear();
    c1a.clear();
    c2a.clear();
    c1b.clear();
    c2b.clear();

    int maxLength = pop.get(getPOP(p1)).maxLength;
    int kromosomSize = k1.size();
    int point = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < kromosomSize; i++) {
        System.out.println("k1 [" + k1.size() + "]" + k1.toString()); //PRINT2
        System.out.println("k2 [" + k2.size() + "]" + k2.toString()); //PRINT2
        System.out.println("");
        if (k1.get(i) == maxLength) {
            point++;
        }
        if (point < cp) {
            c1a.add(k1.get(i));
            c2a.add(k2.get(i)); //ERROR
        } else {
            c1b.add(k1.get(i));
            c2b.add(k2.get(i));
        }

    }
    c1.addAll(c1a);
    c1.addAll(c2b);
    c2.addAll(c2a);
    c2.addAll(c1b);
    Individu C1 = new Individu(c1, "f.fasta");
    Individu C2 = new Individu(c2, "f.fasta");
    C1.calculateFitness();
    pop.add(C1);
    C2.calculateFitness();
    pop.add(C2);
}
```

When I run the program, at some point it work. And after a few generation it create error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.LinkedList.checkElementIndex(LinkedList.java:555)
    at java.util.LinkedList.get(LinkedList.java:476)
    at SKRIPSI.GA.crossover(GA.java:120)
    at SKRIPSI.GA.siklusGA(GA.java:224)
    at SKRIPSI.GA.main(GA.java:249)
Java Result: 1

 GA.java:120 pointed at c2a.add(k2.get(i));
```

Then I tried to print k1 and k2 variable, at PRINT1 and PRINT2. When the error happend, at PRINT2 the k2 become null. Here is the example:

```
PRINT1
k1 [27][5, 4, 11, 6, 16, 9, 13, 10, 2, 15, 8, 17, 2, 10, 7, 15, 9, 11, 4, 3, 12, 6, 17, 0, 1, 7, 17]
k2 [27][0, 11, 13, 1, 10, 8, 15, 16, 14, 7, 3, 17, 16, 11, 8, 10, 13, 14, 4, 3, 15, 9, 17, 12, 3, 9, 17]

PRINT2
k1 [27][5, 4, 11, 6, 16, 9, 13, 10, 2, 15, 8, 17, 2, 10, 7, 15, 9, 11, 4, 3, 12, 6, 17, 0, 1, 7, 17]
k2 [0][]
```

Whereas between PRINT1 and PRINT2 there are no modification of variable k1 and k2. This error will be gone if I change to this:

```
List<Integer> k1 = pop.get(getPOP(p1)).getKromosom();
List<Integer> k2 = pop.get(getPOP(p2)).getKromosom();
List<Integer> c1 = new LinkedList<>();
List<Integer> c2 = new LinkedList<>();
List<Integer> c1a = new LinkedList<>();
List<Integer> c2a = new LinkedList<>();
List<Integer> c1b = new LinkedList<>();
List<Integer> c2b = new LinkedList<>();
```

But I got JavaHeap error because I make too many instance.

**UPDATE1:**
This is getPop method, only return number:

```
public int getPOP(int p) {
        return popSIZE - p - 1;
    }
```

`int maxLength = pop.get(getPOP(p1)).maxLength;` only return number in reverse direction. For example `popSIZE=10` and `p=3` then maxLength will select `pop.get(6)`.maxLength. maxLength is an attribut inside Individu object. This is line where maxLength is assigned:

```
int temp = 0;



     for (int i = 0; i < f.size(); i++) {
            if (temp < f.getSequence(i).length()) {
                temp = f.getSequence(i).length();
            }
        }
maxLength = (int) (Math.ceil((double) (temp * k)));
```

k is some double (in my case 1.2) and f is sequence database.

pop is an ArrayList : `List<Individu> pop = new ArrayList<>();`, so get is method for calling those list.

Also, in first generation k1 and k2 work fine, and in second generation the error shows. And calling for k2 only in this method, I've search there is no other method that call k2. I tried to solve this overnight, and it is the right line that show the error (because when I click on the error it bring me directly to the error line). Maybe NetBeans can be wrong about pointing an error?

**UPDATE2:**
Because maxLength is always 27 in this case, I tried to change it become `int maxLength = 27;`, and it still show error.

You can download full code here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ish2lxh4jzro8zq/AADJfobUR8GUW7nzXtcpjyINa?dl=0

Comment: _"when I use clear(), it affect another variable become null"_ no, there is no evidence of anything becoming null. Your error has to do with a list being empty.  Since you use global variables all over the place you probably have a side-effect in one of the methods you haven't shown, either `pop.get()` or `getPOP()`.  Show the code for those methods.

Comment: @JimGarrison all the logging seems to be happening within the loop, so I would not think it comes from the "global variables". I'm not sure it's the real code being executed to be honest, or that it is the right line

Comment: Between PRINT1 and PRINT2 you have `int maxLength = pop.get(getPOP(p1)).maxLength;`. Either method could be clearing `k2`.

Comment: @JimGarrison oh yeah I missed the first one, I thought there was a typo and that he wrote `PRINT2` twice. That makes more sense now

Comment: please see my update @JimGarrison

Comment: please see my update @Dici

Comment: Show the code for `pop.get()`. We're not going to wade through your entire project to find the code. If you want help, HELP US to help you.

Comment: @JimGarrison I already explain that pop is an arrayList. pop.get is method from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: OK. We don't have the context to run your code. The only way you're going to solve this is to step through it one line at a time starting just below `PRINT1` and figuring out how `k2` is getting cleared.  Please do this and report on the results.

Answer (score -1):

You perform `get` on k2 without checking its size first. If the list is smaller than the index you pass it (or--the more extreme case--if the list is empty), that is to be expected.

Comment: Care to explain why this was downvoted? I see that you have **heavily** modified the original question, but my answer is still valid. If k2 is empty and you perform `get(0)` on it, that's always going to give you an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: I didn't downvoted. My update is to explain Jim Garrison and Dici comment. Between PRINT1 and PRINT2 there are no modification of k2, but in PRINT2 size of k2 become 0, that what I'm confused about.